# Trying to get Strategie,entry and if condtion to work

Tags: pine-script

I am having some problems with using strategy.entry and the stop comand.
I want the strategy.entry to be true  when strategy.position_size == 0 and low > long_1 and low < long_2.

```
//@version=4
strategy("Turtle Project",overlay= true)
entry_1 =  input(55) 
profit_1 =  input(20)             

long_1 = float(na)                                                             
long_1:= if high[entry_1] >= highest(high,entry_1)                   
    high[entry_1]                                                            
else                                                                              
    long_1[1]                                                                   

entry_2 =  input(20) 
profit_2 =  input(10)             

long_2 = float(na)                                                             
long_2:= if high[entry_2] >= highest(high,entry_2)                   
    high[entry_2]                                                            
else                                                                              
    long_2[1]                                                                   


profit2 = float(na)                                                            
profit2:= if low[profit_2] <= lowest(low,profit_2)                   
    low[profit_2]                                                            
else                                                                           
    profit2[1]                      


stop_2 = input(2)/100  

x = strategy.position_size == 0  and low > long_1 and low < long_2 ? true : false
barcolor(x ? color.blue : na)

if strategy.position_size == 0 and low > long_1 and low < long_2
    strategy.entry("longlong_3",strategy.long, stop=long_2)
stoploss_2 = lowest(low,1) <= long_2 and highest(high,1) >= long_2
stoploss2 = float(na)
stoploss2:= stoploss_2 ? strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stop_2) : stoploss2[1]
stoploss__2 = max(stoploss2,profit2)

if high > long_2 and strategy.position_size > 0
     strategy.exit("exit_2 ","longlong_3",stop=stoploss__2)

plot(long_1,color=color.red ,linewidth=3)
plot(long_2,color=color.blue,linewidth=3)
plot(profit2,color=color.blue,  linewidth=1)
plot(stoploss2,style=plot.style_circles, color=color.red)
```

I hope somebody knows how to fix my problem.

[image]

Comment: According to your screenshot, you already have this working: as the condition became true at the bar you are pointing, the strategy put an order and it was filled the very next tick (which seems to be `open` of the next bar). Anyway, if you'd like to enter at the same bar there is a way to enter at the current's bar `close` - use the `process_orders_on_close` param of the `strategy` function, so it'll be like that: `strategy("Turtle Project",overlay= true, process_orders_on_close=true)`

Comment: I want to entrer at the line not at the close or open, thats why i use the stop function in strategie.entry. I only dont know why thare is an atry at the left when the condition is  not true

Comment: So you just want to get rid of that first trade, but the second one is correct?

Comment: yes thats true.

Comment: i olso think its wierd that the first trade took place because the condition was not true at that candle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because the condition became `true` in January-February 2018 (plot the value of the condition to see when it was true: `plot(strategy.position_size == 0 and low > long_1 and low < long_2 ? 10000 : 0, color=color.green)`), and then the order was sent to an exchange and has never been cancelled, so it waited since then. To fix the problem, just use `strategy.cancel`:

```
if strategy.position_size == 0 and low > long_1 and low < long_2
    strategy.entry("longlong_3",strategy.long, stop=long_2)
else
    strategy.cancel("longlong_3")
```

That should work.

Comment: Awesome. By the way, If it works, then it is a good approach to click that gray mark sign on the left of the answer.